# upload image on facebook ios

Tags: iphone

please help me to upload image on facebook using iphone app.here i dont have the url.i just only have the image.but i cant upload it on face book.if i can use an url then i can simply upload it.please help me.

please send me the code for upload image.
i already create facebook instance and other codes relative to fbconnect ios.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The DemoApp that comes with the facebook ios api contains the code to upload a photo in the sample:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/DemoApp

```
/**
 * Upload a photo.
 */
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
  NSString *path = @"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg";
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 img, @"picture",
                                 nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName:@"photos.upload"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
  [img release];
}
```

Comment: Do i have to take care to display a ActivityIndicator/Spinner for my own? I´ve thought that this might be already included within the Facebook SDK. Is it? How do you handle that?