# Posting a photo to Facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, uiimage

I am trying very hard to find some sample codes for posting on facebook. Below is the code i found. However, may i know how to modify it in order to me to post a image instead of text ?

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"Enter your message:";
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@ got straight A's!\",\"href\":\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/\",\"caption\":\"%@ must have gotten real lucky this time!\",\"description\":\"\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/themes/raywenderlich/images/logo.png\",\"href\":\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/\"}]}", _facebookName, _facebookName];
dialog.actionLinks = @"[{\"text\":\"Get MyGrades!\",\"href\":\"http://www.raywenderlich.com/\"}]";
[dialog show];
```

Also the image i am trying to post is a overlapping image. which means it has no file name on it. It is property declared named imageall as the code below.

```
CGRect subviewFrame3 = [self.comment.superview convertRect:self.comment.frame toView:self.imageall]; [self.imageall addSubview:self.comment]; self.comment.frame = subviewFrame3;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.imageall.frame.size);
[self.imageall.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

self.outputView.image = image;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488266/upload-image-on-facebook-ios/5488367#5488367

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
- (void)uploadPhoto:(id)target {

//Just for demonstration.
    NSString *path = @"http://www.facebook.com/images/devsite/iphone_connect_btn.jpg";
    NSURL    *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage  *img  = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    NSDictionary *params = nil;
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.photos.upload" params:params dataParam:(NSData*)img];

}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I tried your method, but nothing popup when i press the button. Thanks

Comment: @Clarence you need to read fbGraphAPI. You will find on google for this. Let me do this for you. Use this link although it does not tell you how to upload photo but you will get the idea implementing FBGraphAPI http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

Comment: the code is from the official demo app... maybe look at the whole project at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/Hackbook/Hackbook/APICallsViewController.m

Answer (score 1):

There is a good frame work called "**AddThis**" to share Images ,links to Facebook,twitter etc (more than 100 social websites).

Look details at [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing#.T2DrEnn4R-4)

You can sign-in/sign-up this site and go to [AddThis for iOS](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.T2Dr5Xn4R-4)

This guide will help you get up and running quickly with the iOS SDK. Check out the full documentation for all the details.

Check it the demo application which is embedded with downloaded zip file.

I ensure you that ,this is a good framework to use.

I have implemented it successfully. ask me if you have any queries. Happy coding.