# image to FaceBook news Feed

Tags: objective-c, facebook, api, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

Does anyone know any public API or a solution to store screenshot images to some public server? Using the image link and add it to your FaceBook wall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found these ones: [PhotoStack](http://photobucket.com/), [imgur](http://imgur.com/) which seems to be a good option (in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know coco code, but here's some pseudo code to help you out.

```
var uploadedImageUrl = PostImageToWebSite(Method="FTP", url="your url", imageName="name", credentials="un:pw", image=screenshotUIImage);
FacebookGraphApi(path="me/photos", httpType="post", source=uploadedImageUrl );
```

or you could upload the bytes

```
var imageBytes = ConvertToBytes(screenshotUIImage);
FacebookGraphApi(path="me/photos", httpType="post", source=imageBytes  );
```

You can also see: [upload image on facebook ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488266/upload-image-on-facebook-ios) for a different way of uploading an image using ios.